# Show dates of this week

Tags: php, date

I am looking for a way to show what the date is or was in the current week perhaps using the week number?

I have tried

```
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('previous monday'));
```

but obviously this doesnt work for the current day or dates in the future

Can anyone help - im a newbie!
Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. What is your aim actually? Do you want the current day of the week?

Comment: Please edit it, its pretty confusing!

Comment: Sorry I dont know how to word it, I want to get the dates for each day of the week from the week number?

Comment: You input the week number and want to get the dates for mo, tue, wed, thur, and friday?

Comment: @Reflic - Yep exactly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The snippet below should give you the previous days according to the week you have entered:

```
$weeks = 1;
$weekdays = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday'];
$first_day_current_year = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, date('Y', time())); // d/m/Y H:i:s => 01/01/YYYY 00:00:00
$n_weeks_after = strtotime('+ '. $weeks . ' week', $first_day_current_year); // d/m/Y H:i:s => 08/01/YYYY 00:00:00
$result = ['reference date' => date('l, d/m/Y, H:i:s', $n_weeks_after)];

foreach ($weekdays as $day) {
  $weekday = strtotime('previous ' . $day, $n_weeks_after);
  $result['previous ' . $day] = date('l, d/m/Y, H:i:s', $weekday);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

In this example, I set `$weeks = 1`, so it ranges from Jan 1st (Thursday) to Jan 7th (Wednesday).
Output below:

```
Array
(
    [reference date] => Thursday, 08/01/2015, 00:00:00
    [previous monday] => Monday, 05/01/2015, 00:00:00
    [previous tuesday] => Tuesday, 06/01/2015, 00:00:00
    [previous wednesday] => Wednesday, 07/01/2015, 00:00:00
    [previous thursday] => Thursday, 01/01/2015, 00:00:00
    [previous friday] => Friday, 02/01/2015, 00:00:00
    [previous saturday] => Saturday, 03/01/2015, 00:00:00
    [previous sunday] => Sunday, 04/01/2015, 00:00:00
)
```

For the current week you can set `$weeks` to:

```
$weeks = date('W', time()); // ISO-8601 week number of year, weeks starting on Monday (added in PHP 4.1.0)
```

You can test it here: http://www.writephponline.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you want the dates of a week you can use this code

```
$week_start = new DateTime();
$week_start->setISODate($year,$week_no);
echo $week_start->format('d-M-Y');
```

I have not tested it but i think it will give you the date of monday from which you can than travel to the other days.

Source: http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/getting-dates-from-week-numbers-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do. Essentially find the last sunday (unless the target date is a sunday) and then just loop over the days until you hit saturday.

```
<?php
//our target timestamp to get the week
// $targetDate = time(); //today
$targetDate = strtotime('1-Jan-2015'); //specific date

//if target day is not day 0 (sunday)
if(date('w', $targetDate) > 0) {
    //get the last sunday
    $sunday = strtotime('last sunday', $targetDate);
} else {
    //target day is sunday, get target date
    $sunday = $targetDate;
}

//if you want shorthand ternary statement, this would work for finding sunday. I wrote it out above so it is easier to understand:
// $sunday = date('w', $targetDate) ? strtotime('last sunday', $targetDate) : $targetDate;

//get the following saturday as our stop point
$saturday = strtotime('saturday', $sunday);

//loop over each day of the week
for(
    $currentDay = $sunday;      //start on sunday
    $currentDay <= $saturday;   //while we aren't on saturday yet
    $currentDay = strtotime('+1 day', $currentDay) //add one day after each loop
){
    //echo out current day's date
    echo date('d-M-Y', $currentDay).'<br>';
}
```

[example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jzR5iR)

I personally prefer this because you can do other stuff in the loop as well such as echo out some values for a specific date.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a function for getting the date using a week number.

First param is the week number (1=first week of the year, mode is set to ISO),

Second param is the week day index (0-6, 0=Monday, 6=Sunday)

The first three params are optional and otherwise being set with current values.

Without any param you will get the current date in the format you used in the question. 

You will get an array of all days of the week if you set the second param (weekday) to 7 (or higher).

With format "H:i" you can see the offset of daylight saving time, e.g. it's "01:00" in summer and "00:00" otherwise.

```
function getWeekDate($week=-1, $weekday=-1, $year=-1, $format="d/m/Y", $mode="ISO") {
    // default is the current
    if($week < 0) { $week = date("W"); }
    if($weekday < 0) { $weekday = date("w")-1; }
    if($weekday < 0) { $weekday+= 7; } // on sundays
    if($year < 0) { $year = date("Y"); }
    $time = strtotime("1 January $year", time());
    $day = date('w', $time);
    if($mode=="ISO") {
        // ISO 8601: first week of the year is the week with the first thursday
        if($day<=4) { $day+= 7; }
    }
    $time+= ((7*$week)+1-$day)*24*3600;
    $return = array();
    for($i=0;$i<=6;$i++) {
        $return[$i] = date($format, $time);
        $time+= 24*3600;
    }
    if(isset($return[$weekday])) {
        $return = $return[$weekday];
    }
    return $return;
}

// Examples:
echo "<br>Current Date: ".getWeekDate();
echo "<br>Monday of the Current Week: ".getWeekDate(-1,0);
echo "<br>Sunday of the Next Week: ".getWeekDate(date("W")+1,6);
echo "<br>All Days of Week 28: ".print_r(getWeekDate(28,7),true);
```